# ActionBar and ActionBar Tabs are pure white

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

How can we make action bar and action bar tabs pure white. I am using android-support-v7-appcompat libs to support backward compatibility. `style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` gives pure black but `style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` does not give pure white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default theme that would give a white action bar. You will need to make a customized action bar for your app.

The developer docs has a good article about customizing the action bar.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

These are the custom styles that you will need to alter.

> res/values/themes.xml

See the **android:background** tag where you can set a drawable for the action bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Apply the theme to your app.

> <application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />

Comment: can we set a drawable on action bar tabs like  we set  on action bar  actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow));

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Check the style resources, and you will be able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: can u please give me an example for that. I am not able to do that.